# Storing arbitrary function objects into a class member container without knowing their declaration signature

Tags: c++, templates, vector, c++17, std-function

I have a class template, and I do not know if I need to have as one of its arguments `class Func` or not. I also do not know if I can arbitrarily store a `std::function` directly into a container without its template argument parameter list. My class looks something like:

```
template<class Data, class Func>
class ThreadManager final {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Data>> storedDataPtrs;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> storedThreadPtrs;

    // Is this valid? I know that `std::function is a class template wrapper 
    // that depends on template argument types. However I do not know
    // what kind of func will be stored...
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::function>> storedFunctionPtrs;

public:
    ThreadManager() = default;
    ~ThreadManager() = default; // will change to clean up containers.
    ThreadManager( const ThreadManager & c ) = delete;
    ThreadManager& operator=( const ThreadManager & c ) = delete;        
};
```

Also similar when I go to write the function that will add the data, thread and function object {`function object`, `function pointer`, `lambda`, `std::function<...>`} Would I be able to declare the parameter for the `function` similarly?

Or should I just use the actual `template` argument itself?

```
 std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Func>> storedFuncPtrs;
```

And if the second case here is the preferred way, then how would I go about to actually store the `func obj`? Would `std::forward` or `std::move` be preferred? Should the method to add in the objects be declared as `Func&& func`?

I'd like to keep this class as generic, modular and portable as possible while trying to maintain modern c++17 best practices.

---

**Edit**

After listening to user Liliscent's advice I think this is what she was stating throughout the comments.

```
std::vector<std::function<Func>>  _storedFuncObjs;
```

Comment: Impossible and bizarre. Even if you can write a function without signature, how can you use it ?

Comment: @liliscent I'm trying to store any arbitrary func object without knowing its type ahead of time. So the idea was to store it as a contained shared_ptr. Would I have to template out its return type, and use variadic parameter list for its arguments? So when this class's method is called to add any kind of function; it can store it into the shared_ptr within the vector.

Comment: The first thing is how you want to use it. Just storing it without any other use is pointless.

Comment: @liliscent I was thinking to have this class take in a data object {single built in type, user defined class or struct etc.}, a corresponding thread with an associated function object that will work on that data. It will store each of them into their respective containers and then by indexing all 3 entries would be handled as a single entity to do multithreading type tasks, such as thread locking, futures, promises, synchronizations, preventing data races etc.

Comment: So for one single Manager, the type is fixed ? In these case I think `std::function` is inevitable. Just template its signature. Or use `Func` and the user should provide a `std::function` type.

Comment: @liliscent That is what I was thinking. I just wasn't sure what direction to go. The class is generic to where it should not need to know what the function looks like; only to be able to store it. I wasn't sure if I could of just used the `template argument` itself, or to store an actual `std::function`.

Comment: You should use `std::function` in this case. Every lambda has a unique type. And storing `std::function` by value is just ok. No need for a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @liliscent I think what was partially confusing me is that if I used `class Func` in the container. Would it be able to store any of the following: {function object, function pointer, lambda or std::function} in the same container.

Comment: @liliscent could you kindly show me a simple example of how the declaration of the member container would look?

Comment: Once you instantiate a class template, the template parameter `Func` is determined and can't be changed. So if you instantiate it with a lambda, you can't even use another lambda to this class.

Comment: @liliscent okay that itself does make sense, so if different lambdas are to be stored; they would have to be either wrapped in a common struct or in a std::function. So this is leaning me to force the user to pass to the class std::function.

Comment: @liliscent Just curious; what if I was to create a generic template structure that can store the func objects either it be a function object, function pointer, a lambda or a std::function; then the user can use that struct to create and wrap their function object and pass that struct to this class and just have a vector of those structs, but wouldn't that be redundant because we already have `std::function`

Comment: The restriction I said above is not that bad. User can supply a lambda or a function pointer. The only thing is internally you need a `std::function` to store. This doesn't restrict your API.

Comment: @liliscent yeah I'm leaning more towards the storing of `std::function`. Now, if the user provided std::function that contained a lambda would it still have the same effect?

Comment: No problem. This is exactly the purpose of `std::function`. Besides lambda, functor can also be stored. Anyway, all callable things with suitable signature.

Answer (score 0):

Why is this class storing `std::thread`s **and** `Data`s **and** `Func`s?

What Callable are you starting those threads with?

- Instances of `Func` applied to `Data`?

  - You only need the `thread`s.
- Instances of `Func` applied to passed arguments, such that a `Data` is produced?

  - Store `std::future<Data>`s (and possibly `thread`s, depending on how you create the futures)
- Instances of `Func` that you will call at some future point?

  - Store `std::packaged_task<Data(Args...)>` and hand out the `std::future<Data>`s those created.

Comment: That's just it; I haven't really done any programming with `multi threading` and I've never really used the library functions... I'm trying to get a grasp of them... I can only understand so much from the `online references...`

Comment: what do you want `ThreadManager` to *specifically do*? At the moment it looks like you are trying to have it own all threads, and everything related to them

Comment: Well I wasn't trying to own all per say; if so I would of had unique_ptr. It's supposed to be a thread resource manager. Keeps track of threads, stores the threads shared memory, the functions and data types assigned to those threads, locks threads, reports when threads are available, if they are busy, or if failed. Support for promises and futures. Maybe even support a priority queue. The manager should be able to take ownership of and transfer it out, etc.

Comment: Maybe I'm over thinking this; instead of the class actually storing the threads and functions directly. Maybe when a thread is instantiated and any action is done to that thread; the manager class could keep track of its `id` and what actions were performed. Then this way through a look up table and the use of external generic function templates, the appropriate actions can be done to them. It was just a way to keep track of the threads and their activity.